# Getting Initialiser error in iOS Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I am working on Apple Swift Programming . I am taking a variable that is initialised in `ViewDidLoad( )` method. But it shows an error like "*Class ABc has no initializer *" . After much searching about this, I got a suggestion to use `init()` method to initialise the variable which you want use. Yet still, I am getting an error like this .[image]

I am not able to make out where am I going wrong here. Kindly guide me on this.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: `Super.init isn't called before returning from initializer` pretty much clear

Answer (score 7):

> Super.init isn't called before returning from initializer

Error is pretty much clear. You are not calling the super class `init()`. But for `UIViewController` you should use any designated initialzer i guess. Try to use `init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder!)`

```
 init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder!)
    {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        // Your intializations
    }
```

Comment: I have add this method but it given the error like "super.init isn't called before returning from initializer" What is mean of this error and how i can this error.

Comment: like init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder!)
    {   // Your intializations
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        
    }

Comment: this doesn't answer the question

Comment: @botbot Have you asked any question here? Then how do you say it doesn't?